# how to Decrease the unbonding Time in substrate?

Tags: polkadot, substrateinterface, blockchain

i am working on `substrate blockchain` its era time and epoch are  set too 2 minutes and when i changed unbonding duration to 4 min in blockchain it is working fine . when i have added evm base to to substrate blochchain with era time and epoch time of 2 min. and when i set unbonding time to any  value rather than the default one i.e 2 min ,10 min etc .when i use my funds to nominate the validator and want to unbond funds the balance is not coming back to account and is still in locked funds . can you please help me out of it . how to change unbonding time  .

Answer (score 0):

I think it isn't related to EVM. Maybe you made some mistakes.

---

Decrease this value: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/911f65be7949342e12601cc3015d5c47e9339de4/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L391

And this value:
https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/911f65be7949342e12601cc3015d5c47e9339de4/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L567

Comment: i have already did this to change the unbonding time but after doing this total balacne is not coming to account after releasing  funds and is still showing in locked funds

Comment: Just check the time, if it is changed. Your question is about the time.

And I think maybe you want https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/b85246bf1156f9f58825f0be48e6086128cc0bbd/frame/staking/src/pallet/impls.rs#L1628? (to get the balance back)

Comment: yeah the  balance is not coming back to account after unbonding funds and funds are in locked funds yeah want to to know why funds are still in locked ones and how to get them back

Comment: Did you check the link? Try making a `withdraw_unbonded` extrinsic.

Comment: yes i have did this also but locked funds are  not getting back into account